# How can I change the background and font color of a selected item in list view?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I tried to change the colors with the `OnCustomDrawItem` event but it has no effect.

```
procedure TForm1.RListCustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
 State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
 if cdsSelected in State then begin
  Sender.Canvas.Brush.Color:=clRed;
  Sender.Canvas.Font.Color:=clYellow;
 end;
end;
```

I use the default `TListView` component with 3 columns an `ViewStyle` set to `vsReport`.

Comment: Have you set `OwnerDraw` property to True ?

Comment: I run this code and I get yellow text on a white background. What do you see.

Comment: I see the windows default colors, as if `CustomDraw` event does'n exist at all. (Tested in Delphi 2009 / Win7 / Windows Classic theme)

Comment: Does your app have the comctl32 v6 manifest? And you have an otherwise default list view. No properties set to non-default values? Other than `ViewStyle` which is presume is `vsReport`. I guess what I am driving at is that you should make sure that we are running the exact same code as you. An MCVE would be good.

Comment: I don't know what is comctl32 manifest, but I've searched my computer and I found many comctl32-v5 files in Windows folder (if it helps). I use the default `TListView` component (from Delphi 2009) with 3 columns an ViewStyle set to `vsReport`.

Comment: If you don't know what "comctl32 v6 manifest" is, then do what you do when faced with any such scenario. Use a websearch. Don't be helpless. When you do that you'll get a gazillion hits. All the same, we probably still need an MCVE. Not least because my attempts to reproduce your output resulted in behaviour different to what you reported. So I for one am not going to spend time chasing this when I've no idea whether or not I'm running the same code as you. You'll need to make a bit of effort to produce an MCVE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The font color only will work as shown in your code.
If you want to change the Background color you will have to Draw the Item and the SubItems on your own and set DefaultDraw to false.

This could look like:

```
procedure TMyForm.ListView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem
                 ; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
  rt, r: TRect;
  s: String;
  i: Integer;
  c:TCanvas;

  // Fit the rect used for TextRect
  Procedure PrepareTextRect;
  begin
    rt := r;
    rt.Left := rt.Left + 5;
    rt.Top := rt.Top + 1;
  end;

begin
  c := Sender.Canvas;
  if (cdsSelected in State) then
  begin
    c.Brush.Color := clRed;
    c.Font.Color := clYellow;
    // will get the rect for Item + Subitems in ViewStyle = vsReport
    r := Item.DisplayRect(drBounds);
    c.FillRect(r);
    // set width to get fitting rt for tfEndEllipsis
    r.Right := r.Left + TListView(Sender).Columns[0].Width;
    s := Item.Caption;
    PrepareTextRect;
    c.TextRect(rt, s, [tfSingleLine, tfEndEllipsis]);

    if TListView(Sender).ViewStyle = vsReport then
    begin // Paint the Subitems if ViewStyle = vsReport
      for i := 0 to Item.SubItems.Count - 1 do
      begin
        r.Left := r.Left + TListView(Sender).Columns.Items[i].Width;
        r.Right := r.Left + TListView(Sender).Columns.Items[i + 1].Width;
        PrepareTextRect;
        s := Item.SubItems[i];
        c.TextRect(rt, s, [tfSingleLine, tfEndEllipsis]);
      end;
    end;
    DefaultDraw := false;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you set ViewStyle to  vsList then you are up and running.

Comment: -1 Setting [`OwnerDraw`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView.OwnerDraw) is not what is needed here. It is not relevant to custom draw events. The documentation which I linked to above says: *Specifies whether the list view receives an OnDrawItem event.
Set OwnerDraw to True and ViewStyle to vsReport in order to allow the list view to receive the OnDrawItem event instead of the default rendering of list items.
Note: This property is independent of the OnCustomDraw, OnCustomDrawItem, OnAdvancedCustomDraw, and OnAdvancedCustomDrawItem events.*

Comment: Regarding your edit. You've totally changed the answer. Better to delete the first answer, and add a new one. Sorts out the votes. But the asker wants to use vsReport.

Comment: Regarding your comment @david Its better to answer the question, than comment on others answers. If you don't have anything constructive to say, thne better keep out of the question.

Comment: That is not correct. Both your answers have been very wide of the mark and it is fine for me to comment. My comments were intended to help you correct your mistakes. My comments are constructive.